# Use parameter to set list in Argo Workflow Template

Tags: argo-workflows

I want to set my `args` section in argo as a parameter.
The problem is that parameters should be a list of strings but Argo wont let me (as far as I know) to set a parameter different then string type.
I don't know the number of argument in advance do I need it to be a list. How can I do so?

```
argo submit something.yaml -p message="["foo", "bar", "baz"]"
```

Instead of `['["foo", "bar", "baz"]']`  what I need is `["foo", "bar", "baz"]`